# Calculate the number of circles that fit on the circumference of another circle

Tags: geometry, collision, trigonometry, detection

I'm looking for an algorithm (or pseudo code) that can calculate the maximum number of (smaller) circles with diameter "s" that can be squeezed into the circumference of another (larger) circle with radius "r" ...

Image: http://teasy.space/images/terracolony-squeezingcircles2.jpg

You can alternate between radius/diameter etc if you wish -- as these are the only 2 parameters (other than the center (large circle) coordinate) that i have, i.e. that are known ...
The outer circles may not overlap but can fit "snug" together ...

After various upgrades to my routine through the years, I'm currently using an algorithm that is not perfect (and it needs to be accurate or the galaxy breaks down lol)
which does a broad interpolation between small outside circle diameter and large inside circle circumference, to somewhat accurately plot the circle count in a polygon style fitting pattern, which causes problems (i.e. overlaps) when using larger outside circles ...

```
; try to fit a random number of circles
num_Circles = Rand( min,max )
; check if the number of circles exceed the maximum that can fit
If num_Circles * SmallCircle_Diameter > LargeCircle_Circumference
    ; adjust the amount accordingly
    num_Circles = LargeCircle_Circumference / SmallCircle_Diameter
End If
```

Another assumption is that the size of the smaller outer circles never exceeds that of the larger inner circle ...
something less to worry about ;)

I'm using this algorithm for one of my projects called Terra Colony, based on Gravity Well, a 2D space/gravity realtime colonization simulation game with moons, planets, stars, black/white holes, etc

Image: http://teasy.space/images/terracolony-squeezingcircles1.jpg

This is an issue that has plagued this project for over a decade!
Hopefully you can point me in the right direction :D

I have previously done many experiments and wrote different programs to find a solution, and have traveled the internet looking for formulas and solutions which in the end are very close, but not close enough! :P

Thank you! <3

Teasy

P.S. I tried to add the tag "circumference" but it apparently requires "1500 reputation" (points i guess, maybe to prevent spam)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is formula that establishes relation between radius of big circle **R**, radius of small circle **r** and number of (touching) small circles **N**

```
R = r / Sin(Pi/N)
```

So maximum number of small circles might be found as

```
Sin(Pi/N) = r / R
Pi / N = arcsin(r / R)
and finally
N = Pi / arcsin(r / R)
```

Example:

```
R=5
r=2.5 
 so 
N = Pi / arcsin(1/2) = 
    Pi / (Pi/6) = 
    6
```

[image]

Comment: wow! thank you so much for your quick response ... let me try it out!

Answer (score 0):

Given the diam. of the small circle 'd' and the number of them 'c'
then the dia. of the large circle 'D' is

D=d/sin(180/c)